# How to get dockwiget splitter-handler?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to get `handle` in `QDockWidget`(red line show in picture),So that when `handle` was `click`, `move`, or `mouse` event and so on.I want to catch it and then do something else,But I can't find how to get it,Can someone know how to get it?

**Code Sample**

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class View(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, QDockWidget("abc", self))
        self.setCentralWidget(QPushButton("ABC"))

app = QApplication([])
v = View()
v.show()
app.exec()
```

[image]

**Below Is New Update**
The view in the `QDockWidget`,When mouse drag handle,I want to the view always show global mini map of the scene,but use re-szie event will be very slow.So I want to get mouse-release event,then use `fitInView` redraw mini map.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import random
import math

r = lambda : random.randint(0, 255)
r255 = lambda : (r(), r(), r())

class Scene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        for i in range(1000*300):
            item = QGraphicsEllipseItem()
            item.setRect(0, 0, r(), r())
            item.setBrush(QColor(*r255()))
            item.setPos(r()*100, r()*100)
            self.addItem(item)

class MainView(QGraphicsView):
    def wheelEvent(self, event: QWheelEvent) -> None:
        factor = math.pow(2.7, event.angleDelta().y()/360)
        self.scale(factor, factor)
        super().wheelEvent(event)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = Scene()
        self.main = MainView()
        self.main.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
        self.side = QGraphicsView()

        self.side.setBackgroundBrush(Qt.black)

        self.main.setScene(self.scene)
        self.side.setScene(self.scene)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.main)

        dock = QDockWidget()
        dock.setWidget(self.side)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, dock)

        #
        dock.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, w: 'QObject', e: 'QEvent') -> bool:
        if isinstance(e, QResizeEvent):
            self.side.fitInView(self.scene.itemsBoundingRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        return super().eventFilter(w, e)

app = QApplication([])
v = MainWindow()
v.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: "do something else" like? That QSplitter is not part of the dock widget, but it's internally created and managed in the (*private*) implementation of the QMainWindow layout manager.

Comment: I want get `handle`  like `QSplitter`, Because I want to catch `handle` event and then do something according relevant event.

Comment: Again, *what is* that something?

Comment: for example, When `handle` was  clicked by mouse left button, then I want to  print  `hello` message in the terminal.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that printing something will be your *actual* purpose. As said, that handle is managed internally and interacts with the private layout, so if you plan on changing its behavior (like limiting its movements) that could be *not* easy, and could require very different implementations than trying to access it for other purposes, so please explain what you *actually* want to do.

Comment: @jre There is no *handle object* as such, because it's created by custom drawing, so there are no events that are specific to it. You can install an event-filter on the dock-widget and monitor its resize-events if you want to receive notifications when the user moves the handle.

Comment: @ekhumoro I want catch when user drag handle and then release  event,if I catch resize-events I need to draw both-side windows every-time,and the windows will be very slow,so I need to catch mouser-release event on the handle.

Comment: @jie Now, *that* is a better explanation of what you need (still not sufficient, though). For future reference, if we ask why you need to do something, it's because we understand from your question that you may be asking something that is too broad or could even be caused by aspects that you are underestimating (see the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Are you trying to catch the resizing in order to improve performance? Can you provide an actual [mre] or at least a more complete context of the issue?

Comment: @musicamante my purpose not just catch mouse-release release on handle, So I say how to get [handle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#handle)  in my post,If I got it, I can do all things, as you say,It not possible to get it for it's internal in qt.If you want  see `minimal reproducible example`, I think I need re-post a new post.

Comment: @jie As pointed out by ekhumoro, that is **not** an actual QSplitterHandle. You cannot get it, as there is *nothing* to get. I don't think you need to create a new post, just [edit] this, create a proper MRE (that *reproduces* the problem!) and be more clear in your requirements; then, when you're finished, add a comment to notify us about the update. Please, seriously, take your time. Don't rush it, be thorough, create a *good* question. Remember to put yourself in other people's shoes: we know *nothing* about what you need to do, nor why. Search about "rubber duck debugging".

Comment: @musicamante  Update Post

Comment: @jie As suspected, you were actually having an XY problem: you were asking the *wrong* question. What you need is not to get the splitter handle, but to optimize drawing when the side view is resized. Now, the *real* question here is: do the contents of the scene change continuously during the lifespan of the program? Because, considering the amount of items in the scene, if the contents don't change (or rarely change), it would be more effective to use a pixmap with a static rendering of the original scene.